# Gradient of squared Frobenius norm of a matrix

Tags: matrices, derivatives, matrix-calculus, least-squares, scalar-fields

In linear regression, the loss function is expressed as

$$ W \mapsto \frac1N \left\| X W - Y \right\|_{\text{F}}^2 $$

where the matrices $X$ and $Y$ are given. Taking the gradient yields

$$ W \mapsto \frac 2N \, X^T( X W - Y ) $$

Why is this so?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Let

$$\begin{array}{rl} f (\mathrm W) &:= \| \mathrm X \mathrm W - \mathrm Y \|_{\text{F}}^2 = \mbox{tr} \left( (\mathrm X \mathrm W - \mathrm Y)^{\top} (\mathrm X \mathrm W - \mathrm Y) \right)\\ &\,= \mbox{tr} \left( \mathrm W^{\top} \mathrm X^{\top} \mathrm X \mathrm W - \mathrm Y^{\top} \mathrm X \mathrm W - \mathrm W^{\top} \mathrm X^{\top} \mathrm Y + \mathrm Y^{\top} \mathrm Y \right)\end{array}$$

Differentiating with respect to $\mathrm W$,

$$\nabla_{\mathrm W} f (\mathrm W) = 2 \, \mathrm X^{\top} \mathrm X \mathrm W - 2 \, \mathrm X^{\top} \mathrm Y = \color{blue}{2 \, \mathrm X^{\top} \left( \mathrm X \mathrm W - \mathrm Y \right)}$$

---

[matrix-calculus](/questions/tagged/matrix-calculus) [scalar-fields](/questions/tagged/scalar-fields) [gradient](/questions/tagged/gradient)

Comment: What about the derivative with respect to $ X $?

Comment: @Royi Aren't $\rm X$ and $\rm Y$ given?

Comment: I'm just saying what's the derivative of $ \left\| X W - Y \right\|_{F}^{2} $ with respect to $ X $. Just curious.

Comment: I get it is $ 2 \left( X W - Y \right) {W}^{T} $.

Comment: @Royi I just got the exact same.

Comment: how did you get 2XTY ? can you show the full step to do the differentiation

Comment: @kong If you want a step-by-step derivation, use the directional derivative.

Comment: i did not study that in my course. how else can i compute the differentiation ?

Comment: @kong You can always use the matrix cookbook.

Comment: wow thank you that is very helpful :) now I just need to understand how the formulas are derived

Comment: @kong The derivatives of the linear terms are easy. Just use the properties of the trace and the definition of the Frobenius inner product. The derivative of the quadratic term is not so easy, but one can use the definition of the directional derivative.

Comment: i cant find the answer in the book to the derivative of tr$(W^TX^TXW)$

Comment: @kong Section 2.5.2, equation 108.

Comment: I get $X^TXW + XX^TW$ How do I get $2X^TXW$ if X is not square ?

Comment: but eq. 108 says $ \frac{d}{dX} X^TBX = BX + B^TX $. So $ \frac{d}{dW} W^TX^TXW = X^TXW + XX^TW $ right ?

Comment: @kong No, because $(X^T X)^T = X^T X$. When you transpose a product of matrices, the order is reversed.

Comment: oohh i cant believe i missed that. thank you very much kind sir !!!

Answer (score 15):

Let $X=(x_{ij})_{ij}$ and similarly for the other matrices. We are trying to differentiate
$$
\|XW-Y\|^2=\sum_{i,j}(x_{ik}w_{kj}-y_{ij})^2\qquad (\star)
$$
with respect to $W$. The result will be a matrix whose $(i,j)$ entry is the derivative of $(\star)$ with respect to the variable $w_{ij}$.

So think of $(i,j)$ as being fixed now. Only some of the terms in $(\star)$ depend on $w_{ij}$. Taking their derivative gives
$$
\frac{d\|XW-Y\|^2}{dw_{ij}}=\sum_{k}2x_{ki}(x_{ki}w_{ij}-y_{kj})=\left[2X^T(XW-Y)\right]_{i,j}.
$$

Comment: I found your answer very helpful! Thanks so much :).

Comment: There's a sum missing in the first expression. It should be: $\sum_{i,j}(\sum_k x_{ik}w_{kj}-y_{ij})^2$

Comment: ... and also in the 2nd expression. It might be easier to use the same indices: $L = \sum_{i}\sum_j(\sum_k x_{ik}w_{kj}-y_{ij})^2$, $\frac{\partial L}{\partial w_{k'j'}}=\sum_i 2(\sum_k x_{ik}w_{kj'}-y_{ij'})x_{ik'} = 2X^T(XW-Y)$.

Comment: This should be accepted :>. Much more intuitive than using trace and expanding everything out. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Just want to have more details on the process. The process should be
Denote $X = [x_{ij}], W = [w_{ij}], Y = [y_{ij}]$, then we have
$$
\left \| XW - Y \right \|^{2} = \sum_{k, j} (\sum_{i} x_{ki} w_{ij} - y_{kj})^{2},
$$
This is a scalar and by taking the derivative w.r.t. the matrix $W$ we get a matrix. By taking $i, j$ as the known number, we get
$$
\frac{d \left \| XW - Y \right \|^{2}}{d w_{ij}} = \sum_{k} 2x_{ki} (\sum_{i} x_{ki} w_{ij} - y_{kj})\\
= \sum_{k} 2x_{ki} (XW - Y)_{kj} \\
= [2 X^{T} (XW - Y)]_{ij}
$$
Thus we have
$$
\frac{d \left \| XW - Y \right \|^{2}}{d W} = 2 X^{T} (XW - Y)
$$
First time answering a question, hope it is right, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Roughly speaking, the $\textbf{Jacobian}$ of $f$ at point $x$ is the matrix/tensor $B$ such that we have \begin{equation}f(x+\delta)=f(x) + B\delta+ o(\|\delta\|).\end{equation}
So, if $$f(W)=\|XW-Y\|_F^2,$$
then
\begin{equation}
f(W+\delta)=\|X(W+\delta)-Y\|_F^2=\|XW-Y+X\delta\|_F^2=\|XW-Y\|_F^2+2\langle XW-Y,X\delta \rangle +\|X\delta\|_F^2.
\end{equation}
Note that we then have
\begin{equation}
f(W+\delta)=f(W)+2\langle X^T( XW-Y),\delta \rangle +o(\|\delta\|)= f(W)+2\left(X^T( XW-Y)\right)^T\delta +o(\|\delta\|).
\end{equation}
So, the Jacobian of $f$ is $2\left(X^T( XW-Y)\right)^T$, implying that the gradient is its transpose.

This Taylor expansion idea is a smart trick to make your life easier while taking derivatives.

Answer (score 0):

Let $U(W;X,Y)=XW-Y$, $L(U;N)=\frac{1}{N}U:U$ ("$:$" denote Frobenius inner product)

Using Fréchet derivative:

$L(U+dU)-L(U)=\frac{1}{N}(tr((U+dU)^T(U+dU))-tr((U^TU))=\frac{1}{N}tr(2U^TdU)=\frac{2}{N}U:dU$

$dL=\frac{2}{N}U:dU$

Also, $U(W+dW)-U(W)=XdW$

$dU=XdW$

By chain rule,

$dL=\frac{2}{N}U:(XdW)=tr(\frac{2}{N}U^TXdW)=(\frac{2}{N}X^TU):dW$

$\frac{dL}{dW}=\frac{2}{N}X^TU=\frac{2}{N}X^T(XW-Y)$