# deriving the formula for multinomial linear regression

Tags: derivatives, normed-spaces, matrix-calculus, machine-learning, linear-regression

I am trying to understand why $\theta_{MLE} = (X^TX)^{-1}X^Ty$ for multinomial linear regression in which we have the Frobenius norm for $min||y-X\theta||^2$
Looking at [this](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~minx/matrixcal.pdf) tutorial, I have hard time to followup with the steps. Is there a better link you could suggest or better way to derive?
[image]

Also, using this [solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2128704/109135), I have:
$||X\theta-y||^2 = tr((X\theta-y)^T(X\theta-y))$
$= tr(\theta^TX^TX\theta - \theta^TX^Ty-y^TX\theta+y^Ty)$

differentiate wrt $\theta$:
$\Delta_\theta f(\theta) = 2X^TX\theta-2X^Ty = 2X^T(X\theta-y)$

I am not sure how could I continue this to end up with $(X^TX)^{-1}X^Ty$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To understand why $\theta_{MLE} = (X^TX)^{-1}X^Ty$, we have to derive the MLE starting from the likelihood function as such:
\begin{equation}
 y = X\theta + \epsilon
\end{equation}
where 
\begin{equation}
 \epsilon \sim \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2 I)
\end{equation}
Then, the PDF of $y$ given all unknown parameters are 
\begin{equation}
 P(y \vert \theta,\sigma^2) 
 =
 \frac{1}{\sqrt {\pi^n{\det( \sigma^2 I)}}}
 exp(-\frac{1}{2}(y - X\theta)^T(\sigma^2 I)^{-1}(y - X\theta))
\end{equation}
we have that
\begin{equation}
 \det( \sigma^2 I) = \sigma^{2n}
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
 (\sigma^2 I)^{-1} = \frac{1}{\sigma^2} I
\end{equation}
So
\begin{equation}
 P(y \vert  \theta, \sigma^2) 
 =
 \frac{1}{\sqrt {\pi^n{\det( \sigma^2 I)}}}
 exp(-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}(y - X\theta)^T(y - X\theta))
\end{equation}
The above is the likelihood function, take the log likelihood and maximize with respect to $\theta$, you get
\begin{equation}
 l(\theta) = \log P(y \vert  \theta, \sigma^2)
 =
 -\log (\pi^n \sigma^{2n})^{0.5} 
 -\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}(y - X\theta)^T(y - X\theta)
\end{equation}
Since we optimize with respect to $X$, then the first term doesn't really affect the optimizaiton, so deriving w.r.t $\theta$ will cancel the first term as 
\begin{equation}
 \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} l(\theta) 
 =
 -\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}
 (- 2X^Ty + 2 X^TX \theta )
 = 0
\end{equation}
which is equivalent to 
\begin{equation}
 - 2X^Ty + 2 X^TX \theta
 =
 0
\end{equation}
i.e.
\begin{equation}
 X^Ty - X^TX \theta
 =
 0
\end{equation}
or
\begin{equation}
 X^Ty 
 =
 X^TX \theta
\end{equation}
If $X^TX$ is invertible, then
\begin{equation}
\theta
=
 (X^TX)^{-1}X^Ty 
\end{equation}

---

### Why $\det \sigma^2 I = \sigma^{2n}$

Because $\sigma^2 I$ is a diagonal matrix of entries $\sigma^2$ so the determinant would be a product of the diagonal entries.

Comment: can you please share a link how you obtained  PDF of y ? thanks

Comment: also a link on why det sigma^2*I is what you wrote would be really helpful

Comment: i have edited @MonaJalal at the end why the determinant is such and here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_distribution is the link that you need to get the PDF of a multinormal distribution