# Frobenius norm differentiation

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, normed-spaces

> Frobenius norm differentiation $X\in R^n$

\begin{align}
f(x) &= \tfrac12\|X^TX-A\|^2_F=\tfrac12\langle X^TX-A,X^TX-A \rangle \\[1ex]
df(x) &= \tfrac12d\bigl(\langle X^TX-A,X^TX-A \rangle\bigl)=\tfrac12\langle d(X^TX-A),d(X^TX-A) \rangle\\
& = \tfrac 42\bigl(\bigl\langle \langle X,dX\rangle \langle X,dX \rangle\bigr\rangle\bigr) =2(X^Tdx)^TX^Tdx=2dxXX^Tdx=2(X^TXdx)^Tdx
\end{align}

Where $\langle x,y \rangle$ is the scalar multiplication.

I don't actually know how to do matrix/vector/norm differentiation. What I come up with is the above. Please, can you help me to differentiate the expression?

Comment: Check this question.
 https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2128462/derivative-of-squared-frobenius-norm-of-a-matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Frobenius product is defined as 
$$A:B = {\rm Tr}(A^TB)$$
The properties of the trace allow terms in such a product to be rearranged in various ways.
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= B:A \\
A:B &= A^T:B^T \\
A:BC &= AC^T:B \;=\; B^TA:C \;=\; etc \\
}$$
This product makes it easy to calculate differentials and gradients involving the Frobenius norm.
$$\eqalign{
\phi &= \tfrac{1}{2}\|M\|_F^2 = \tfrac{1}{2}M:M \\
d\phi &= \tfrac{1}{2}\big(M:dM+dM:M\big) = M:dM \\
}$$
For your current problem, set $M=(X^TX-A)$
$$\eqalign{
d\phi &= M:dM \\
 &= M:(X^TdX+dX^TX) \\
 &= XM:dX + MX^T:dX^T \\
 &= XM:dX + XM^T:dX \\
 &= X(M+M^T):dX \\
\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial X} &= X(M+M^T) \\
\\
}$$
Another general rule to learn is the differential of a product,
$$d(A\star B) = dA\star B + A\star dB$$
where $\star$ can be nearly any product you are likely to encounter, e.g.  Frobenius, Kronecker, Hadamard, Dyadic, Matrix, Tensor.

And the quantites $(A,B)$ can be any scalar, vector, matrix, or tensor pair which are dimensionally compatible with said product. But you must maintain their relative order, i.e. $A$ before $B$.

Comment: So, $X^TdX=X$ and $dX^TX=X^TdX^T$? Did I understand it right? If so can yo explain why they are equal to those values?

Comment: The rule for rearranging a Frobenius product says $M:X^TdX=XM:dX$. This is **not** the same as saying $X^TdX=X$, which is absolutely false.