# How to get the derivative of this matrix function where the variables occur 2 times?

Tags: matrices, derivatives, normed-spaces, matrix-calculus

$$ \left\|Y-XX^T \right\|_{\text{F}}^2$$

where $X,Y$ are matrices. Taking derivative w.r.t $X$ yields

$$-2(Y-XX^T)X$$

Why is this so?

Comment: Did you try to search within MSE? There are several questions like this. For instance, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2128462/derivative-of-squared-frobenius-norm-of-a-matrix?rq=1. I hope that helps.

Comment: Yes. But here the variables occur 2 times. The things become different.

Answer (score 1):

Some notations:

- Trace and Frobenius product relation $$\left\langle A, B C\right\rangle={\rm tr}(A^TBC) := A : B C$$
- Cyclic properties of Trace/Frobenius product
  \begin{align}
  A : B C 
   &= BC : A \\
   &= A C^T   :  B \\
   &= A^T: C^TB^T \\
   &= {\text{etc.}} \cr
  \end{align}

Let $f := \left\|Y - XX^T\right\|_F^2 \equiv Y - XX^T:Y - XX^T$.

Obtain the differential followed by the gradient (aka Jacobian).
\begin{align}
df  
&= d\left(Y - XX^T:Y - XX^T \right) \\
&= \left[\left(-dXX^T - XdX^T \right):Y - XX^T \right] + \left[Y - XX^T : \left(-dXX^T - XdX^T \right)\right] \\
&= -2 \left(Y - XX^T\right) : \left(dXX^T + XdX^T \right) \\
&= \left[-2 \left(Y - XX^T\right) : dXX^T \right] + \left[-2 \left(Y - XX^T\right) : XdX^T \right]\\
&= \left[-2 \left(Y - XX^T\right)X : dX \right] + \left[-2 X^T\left(Y - XX^T\right) : dX^T \right]\\
&= \left[-2 \left(Y - XX^T\right)X : dX \right] + \left[-2 \left(Y^T - XX^T\right)X : dX \right]\\
\end{align}

Thus, the gradient is
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial X} = -2\left[\left(Y + Y^T \right) - 2XX^T\right]X.
\end{align}