# Gradient of least-squares loss function

Tags: matrices, derivatives, matrix-calculus, least-squares, matrix-norms

Given $m \times n$ matrix $\bf X$ and $m \times p$ matrix $\bf Y$, define the loss function in $n \times p$ matrix $\bf R$

$$ \operatorname{Loss} ({\bf R}) := \| \mathbf{X} \mathbf{R} - \mathbf{Y} \|_F^2 $$

where the square of the Frobenius norm of $n \times m$ matrix $\mathbf{A}$ is defined as

$$ \| \mathbf{A} \|_F^2 = \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^m a_{ij}^2 $$

I have to compute the gradient $\nabla_{{\bf R}} \operatorname{Loss}$. My source says:

$$ \nabla_{{\bf R}} \operatorname{Loss} ({\bf R}) = \dfrac2m \mathbf{X}^T (\mathbf{X} \mathbf{R} - \mathbf{Y} ) $$

but I am not sure how to obtain this result.

Comment: What have you tried so far? A good tip for taking matrix derivatives that I used when I wasn't as comfortable with matrix calculus was to simply take the derivative with respect to one element of the matrix (say $R_{ij}$), and write everything in summation form. Also, I think you might be missing a $1/m$ factor in your original loss expression.

Comment: Also, if you're still stuck, you can find the derivation here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2128462/derivative-of-squared-frobenius-norm-of-a-matrix

Comment: Do you agree with my edits?  Which source is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a colon to denote the trace/Frobenius product
$$\eqalign{
A:B \;=\; \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij}B_{ij}
 \;=\; {\rm Tr}(A^TB)  \;=\; {\rm Tr}(AB^T) \\
}$$
then the derivative/gradient is fairly simple to calculate
$$\eqalign{
W &= XR-Y \\
dW &= X\,dR\\
Loss &= \big\|W\big\|^2_F \,\;=\; W:W \\
d\,Loss &= 2W:dW \;=\; 2W:X\,dR \;=\; 2X^TW\color{red}{:dR} \\
\frac{\partial\,Loss}{\color{red}{\partial R}} &= 2X^TW \;=\; 2X^T(XR-Y) \\
}$$
So the answer from your source is off by a factor of $\left(\frac 1m\right)$

Comment: Thank you very much. Can you explain to me the part `d Loss = 2W:dW`?

Comment: The Frobenius product is commutative,  so taking the differential of $W\!:\!W$ is analogous to taking the differential of the scalar expression $w^2,\,$ i.e. $$d(w^2)=2w\,dw \quad\longrightarrow\quad d(W\!:\!W)=2W:dW$$

Comment: Thank you very much!