# Derivative of Frobenius norm with respect to scalar

Tags: matrices, derivatives, normed-spaces, trace

Can anyone explain to me why $$\frac{d}{d\theta }\left\|\textbf{Aw}-\theta(1-c)\textbf{1} \right\|^{2}= 0$$ is equivalent to $$2(1-c)\textbf{1}^T(\theta(1-c)\textbf{1}-\textbf{Aw})=0$$? I'm not very good with the term trace or derivative of matrices. So please also give me some references for me. Even the explanation I found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3962907/calculate-derivative-of-frobenius-norm-for-loss-function-using-matrix-calculus) could not enlighten me. The part that still confuses me especially is why the matrix $\textbf{1}$ is transposed and moved to the front. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Just apply the Leibniz-rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$
\def\t{\theta}\def\l{\lambda}\def\o{{\tt1}}\def\p{\partial}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\trace#1{\operatorname{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\fracLR#1#2{\LR{\frac{#1}{#2}}}
\def\gradd#1#2{\frac{d #1}{d #2}}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
$Define the vector variables
$${
x = \LR{1-c}\o, \qquad
z = \LR{\t x - Aw}, \qquad
\c{dz = d\t\;x}
}$$
Write your function in terms of these variables,
then calculate the differential and gradient.
$$\eqalign{
\l &= \;\|z\|^2 \;=\; z^Tz \\
d\l &= 2\,\c{dz}^Tz = 2\,\c{d\t\,x}^Tz \\
\gradd{\l}{\t} &= 2x^Tz \;=\; 2\LR{\t\,x^Tx-x^TAw} \\
}$$
Setting the gradient to zero yields
$$\eqalign{
\t\,x^Tx &= x^TAw \qiq \t = \frac{x^TAw}{x^Tx} \\
}$$

Comment: how do you get $2  dz^T z$?

Comment: @Haha For real vectors the inner product is commutative, i.e. $\;x^Ty=y^Tx.\;$ Therefore $$d(z^Tz)\;=\;z^Tdz+dz^Tz\;=\;2\,dz^Tz$$