# How did they get the final result here?

Tags: matrices, derivatives, matrix-calculus, least-squares, scalar-fields

I am trying to understand the answer of this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2128462/derivative-of-squared-frobenius-norm-of-a-matrix/2128704).  How do you get this?

$$\nabla_{\mathrm W}\left(\mbox{tr} \left( \mathrm W^{\top} \mathrm X^{\top} \mathrm X \mathrm W - \mathrm Y^{\top} \mathrm X \mathrm W - \mathrm W^{\top} \mathrm X^{\top} \mathrm Y + \mathrm Y^{\top} \mathrm Y \right)\right)$$ $$= 2 \, \mathrm X^{\top} \mathrm X \mathrm W - 2 \, \mathrm X^{\top} \mathrm Y$$

Specifically, I want to know what kind of magic happens to these:

$$-\mathrm Y^{\top} \mathrm X \mathrm W - \mathrm W^{\top} \mathrm X^{\top} \mathrm Y$$

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

**Alternative approach**

The Frobenius product by a colon can be defined as
\begin{align}
{\rm Tr}\left( A^T B C \right) := A: BC
\end{align}

We will use the cyclic property of trace, e.g.,
\begin{align}
A: BCD = B^T A: CD = B^TAD^T: C
\end{align}

To find the gradient, we will exploit differential. To this end, we can rewrite the problem at hand as
\begin{align}
f &:= {\rm Tr}\left( W^TX^TXW - Y^TXW - W^TX^TY + Y^TY \right) \\
  &\equiv XW : XW - Y:XW - XW:Y + Y:Y
\end{align}

Compute the differential and then gradient.
\begin{align}
df 
&= XdW : XW + XW : XdW - Y:XdW - Y:XdW  \\
&= 2X^TXW : dW - X^TY:dW - X^TY:dW  \\
&= \left(2X^TXW - 2X^TY\right):dW 
\end{align}

The gradient is
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial W}
&=  2X^TXW - 2X^TY .
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks, but I am looking to uncover the magic with those two terms.

Comment: As commented by mathcounterexamples.net, let $M=Y^T XW$, then $\operatorname{Tr}\left( M \right) = \operatorname{Tr}\left( M^T\right)$, which explains your mystery...

Answer (score 0):

The trace of a matrix is equal to the trace of the transpose. So

$$\operatorname{tr}(Y^T XW+ W^TX^TY)= 2\operatorname{tr}(Y^TXW)$$ and

$$W \mapsto 2\operatorname{tr}(Y^TXW)$$ is linear so its derivative is equal to itself. See [derivative in product in trace](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Ejduchi/projects/matrix_prop.pdf) if required.

Comment: For the first line, you take the individual trace?  Can you provide the details that are not shown?

Answer (score 0):

And for the other part, $\operatorname{tr}(AB)=\operatorname{tr}(BA)$, so
$$\operatorname{tr}(W^{\top}X^{\top} X W)=\operatorname{tr}(X^{\top} X W W^{\top})$$ and he seems to be differentiating inside the trace to take a constant out
$$\nabla_W(\operatorname{tr}(X^{\top} X W W^{\top}))=X^{\top} X \nabla_W(\operatorname{tr}(W W^{\top}))=2X^{\top} X W$$ but I guess this needs some justification even if true.