# Can I swap the positions in this equation?

Tags: matrices, derivatives, matrix-calculus, least-squares, scalar-fields

I am looking at this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2128462/derivative-of-squared-frobenius-norm-of-a-matrix/2128704).  I wonder if I have:

$$\left\|Y-XW\right\|_{\text{F}}^2$$

Does taking derivative w.r.t $W$ yields this?

$$-2X^T(Y-XW)$$

Comment: Let $\phi(W)=\left\|Y-XW\right\|_{\text{F}}^2$, write out $\phi(W+H)-\phi(W)$ using the trace and collect linear terms in $H$.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by swapping positions.

Comment: Also, that is the gradient, not the derivative as such.

Comment: @copper.hat, the original question is about $\left\|XW-Y\right\|_{\text{F}}^2$ and mine is about $\left\|Y-XW\right\|_{\text{F}}^2$.  Hence, positions swapped.  Also, I made the edit to account for the missing $-2$.

Comment: It doesn't matter whether you write $\|Y-XW\|_F^2$ or $\|XW-Y\|_F^2$, the gradient is same.