# Frobenius norm minimization problem

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization, normed-spaces, least-squares

Given matrices $A, B \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$, I want to solve the following least-squares problem

$$ \min_{X \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}} \| A - B X \|_F^2 $$

where $\| \cdot \|_F$ is the Frobenius norm. In this problem, $m \ge n$.

Does anyone know how to solve this? Or possibly convert it into an ordinary least squares problem?

Comment: The pseudoinverse $B^+$ can be calculated by almost any numerical library, in terms of which the least-squares solution is simply $\;X=B^+A\quad$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that for $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n},$

\begin{align*}
\| A \|^{2}_{F} = \textrm{trace}(A^{\top} A).
\end{align*}

With this in mind, consider the following (very relevant) post:

[Derivative of squared Frobenius norm of a matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2128462/derivative-of-squared-frobenius-norm-of-a-matrix/2128704)

Hence, you can differentiate your expression in the usual way (being mindful of 2nd-order conditions for optimality), and find a solution to your optimization problem.

Additionally, a useful reference for a variety of matrix identities (including matrix calculus) is "The Matrix Cookbook" by Kaare Brandt Petersen and Michael Syskind Pedersen. A version of the document can be found here:

[https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~hwolkowi/matrixcookbook.pdf](https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/%7Ehwolkowi/matrixcookbook.pdf)

Comment: thanks this helps a lot

Answer (score 1):

For future readers, the post linked by the accepted answer leads to the following result,
$$
X = (B^T B)^{-1} B^T A
$$
This system could be solved with a Cholesky decomposition of $B^T B$, however a more numerically stable method is to use a $QR$ decomposition of $B$.
\begin{align}
\left|\left| A - B X \right|\right|_F^2 &= \left|\left| A - Q \pmatrix{R \\ 0} X \right|\right|_F^2 \\
&= \left|\left| Q^T A - \pmatrix{R \\ 0} X \right|\right|_F^2 \\
&= \left|\left| C_1 - R X \right|\right|_F^2 + || C_2 ||_F^2
\end{align}
where
$$
Q^T A = \pmatrix{C_1 \\ C_2}
$$
and $C_1$ is the first $n$ rows of $Q^T A$. Then, we just need to minimize the term $|| C_1 - R X||_F^2$ which can be made zero by the choice,
$$
X = R^{-1} C_1
$$
This assumes of course that $B$ is invertible.