# Differentiate matrix expression (linear regression)

Tags: linear-regression

$$\frac{d}{dw} [w^TX^TXw - 2w^TX^Ty+y^Ty] = 2(X^TXw-X^Ty)$$

I do not understand how the RHS was obtained -- are there certain matrix differentiation properties which can be used to show this? Why does differentiating w.r.t. $w$ get rid of the $w^T$ (and not $w$) from each of the terms?

Comment: Expand the matrix products and compute the partial derivatives $\frac{\partial}{\partial w_i}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(x^TBx)=(B+B^T)x
$$
The first term in your problem gives
$$
w^T(X^TX+X^TX)=2X^TX w
$$

The last term simplifies to $\boldsymbol{0}$.

By noting that $$
\frac{\partial x^T a}{\partial x}=a
$$
We generalize this to the matrix $A$ instead of $a$ so the middle term gives:
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial w}{(-2w^T X^T y)}=-2X^Ty
$$

Comment: Thanks so much!

Answer (score 3):

Notice that
$$w^TX^TXw−2w^TX^Ty+y^Ty=\langle Xw-y,Xw-y\rangle =\|Xw-y\|^2,$$
where $\langle \cdot,\cdot \rangle $ is the inner (or the dot) product of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

If you denote $$f(w)=\langle Xw-y,Xw-y\rangle,$$ then the inner product properties leads to
$f(w+h)=f(w)+2\langle Xw-y,Xh\rangle+\langle Xh,Xh\rangle=f(w)+2\langle X^T(Xw-y),h\rangle+\langle Xh,Xh\rangle$.

If you use the definition and properties of [directional derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directional_derivative), you find that $$f(w+h)=f(w)+\langle \nabla f(w),h\rangle + \langle Xh,Xh\rangle,$$ and hence $$\frac{d f}{d w}=\nabla f(w)=2X^T(Xw−y).$$

You can find more comments on [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2128462/derivative-of-squared-frobenius-norm-of-a-matrix#answer-3727137), and in [Matrix Calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus). Try also search for ''\|Xw-y\|^2 derivative'' on SearchOnMath.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks to the advice. I did an edit.

Comment: Thanks so much!