# Minimizing $\|A−XB\|^2_F$

Tags: matrices, matrix-calculus, least-squares, quadratic-programming, scalar-fields

> Find a closed form solution for $$\underset{X}{\operatorname{argmin}} \|A−XB\|^2_F$$ where $\| \cdot \|_F$ denotes the Frobenius norm.

---

I have found this [thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2128462). Not sure if it helps here though. Any ideas? Do I just start analyzing the above given the Frobenius norm and then simply calculate the derivatives? Is there a better way to go?

Comment: Please learn how to write formulas in Latex , here `$$\operatorname{argmin}_X \|A−XB\|^2_F$$ ` (and take note of use the name "argmin")

Comment: It helps! Since your problems is convex (linear function composed with Frobenius  norm), only knowing the function's critical points is enough to solve the convex problem. Actually, I would say to you to vectorize the problem by using the Frobenius norm definition. This is a least-square problem

Comment: $X=AB^+$, where $B^+$ denotes the [Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse) of $B$, is a minimiser.

Comment: Why don't you start by using the definition of the Frobenius norm?

Comment: @JeanMarie Rather than defining a new operator, you can cheat and combine two existing ones, i.e. `$$\arg\!\min_X$$`

Comment: @greg Very astute !